# Adding new node to aerospike cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, addition, aerospike

We are having a two node cluster of aerospike. We thought of adding two more nodes to the cluster. As soon I added them we are getting queue too deep error on new nodes and as well Device  over load on client.

I tried of making migrate-max-num-incoming from 256 to 4. Still the issue persists.

What is the best way to add a new node to cluster without impacting the clients.

More info:
1) We are using SSD based installation
2) we are using mesh node architecture

Comment: Can you provide : asadm -e "show config like migrate" and asadm -e "show config like defrag". Could also check defrag rate in aerospike.log on existing nodes once you added the node.

Comment: 2nd @lvolmar, lowering migrate-max-num-incoming will prevent new immigrations from starting while there are more than 4 already but will not stop the existing immigrations.

Answer (score 3):

Your storage is not keeping up.

The following links should help:

1- Understand device overload:

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/device-overload/733

2- Understand how to tune migrations:

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/migration#lowering-the-migration-rate

3- This could also be caused by defragmentation on the previous nodes in the cluster as data migrating out will cause a vacuum effect and could cause defragmentation activity to pick up, in which case you would want to slow down defragmentation by tuning defrag sleep down:

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#defrag-sleep

Answer (score 2):

Add one node at a time. Wait till migrations are complete before adding second node. (I assume all nodes are running the same version of Aerospike and configuration is consistent, all have same namespace defined etc.)

Comment: I tried that as well, the problem is during migration, actual writes are failing with device overload error.

Comment: what is your aerospike server version?  community edition i assume?

Comment: Also, how many namespaces do you have and what is defrag-lwm-pct set to for each namespace using SSD storage?  Can you share your namespace configuration?